# Find a similarity of two vector shapes

Tags: algorithm, vector, similarity

Looking for any information/algorithms relating to comparing vector graphics. E.g. say there two point collections or vector files with two almost identical figures. I want to determine that a first figure is about 90% similar to the second one.

Comment: This is in general. Think if this will work for 2D, it's not so hard to make it for 3D.

Comment: Quartic equations was a piece of cake so I guess quintic shouldn't be a problem... Actually I have no clue concerning 2D versus 3D fuzzy vector compare but I think it could be a mistake to be sure that it's equally hard.

Comment: What do you mean by similar?  Is there a point-by-point match-up that you know, and you want to see how much these points have moved; or are they similar points but with a few missing; or do you mean similar shapes, but possibly scaled and rotated?  I assume you just mean geometry, right, not similar colors for example?

Comment: Similar from geometry point of view only. No colors, other properties or points number is important. Shapes could be scaled or rotated, but what is important is the shape geometry itself. Your answer looks in right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A common way to test for similarity is with [image moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment).  Moments are intrinsically translationally invariant, and if the objects you compare might be scaled or rotated you can use moments that are invariant to these transformations, such as [Hu moments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_moment#Rotation_invariant_moments).

Most of the programs I know would require rasterized versions of the vector objects; but the moments could be calculated directly from the vector graphics using a Green's Theorem approach, or a more simplistic approach that just identifies unique (unordered) vertex configurations would be to convert the Hu moment integrals to sums over the vertices -- in a physics analogy replacing the continuous object with equal point masses at each vertex.

There is a paper on a tool called [VISTO](http://books.google.com/books?id=I47_sQnnf_IC&pg=PT275&lpg=PT275&dq=VISTO+%22vector+graphics%22&source=bl&ots=7HrxhTq6QR&sig=1_Bv7oNsbDKxOM5JwOU31dFf-MI&hl=en&ei=YfC3SrCUAovQ8Qb5282TDw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=3#v=onepage&q=VISTO%20%22vector%20graphics%22&f=false) that sorts vector graphics images (using moments, I think), which should certainly be useful for more details.

Comment: [Here's another link](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030643790900101X) to the VISTO approach. (btw, it's not free, and given that it's Elsevier, I'd assume it never will be.)

Answer (score 2):

You could search for fingerprint matching algorithms. Fingerprints are usually converted to a set of points with their relative location to each other, which makes it basically the same problem as yours.

Answer (score 0):

You could transform it to a non-vector graphic and then apply standard image analysis techniques like SIFT points, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I know, but I asked this question specifically about vector graphics in hope that there are existing ways to solve such problems without "go back" to raster algorithms. It's a theoretical question and I don't have a specific problem to solve, so I can't find an example of drawbacks of raster algorithms right now, but I'm sure their vector analogs should be more quality and universal.